# While obtaining hash files, some folders and files from the directory are not showing up

Tags: python, file, hash, directory, os.walk

My code was working just fine before adding the hash function.  I was getting the list of all folders and files in my directory in the Pretty Table.  Once I added the hash function, I got maybe 5 of the files in that directory with hashes in the table.  I am not sure where I have gone wrong. Please forgive me, I am new to this.  We are not learning to code from scratch, but have to modify existing codes to function the way we need it to.

```
# Python Standard Libaries 
import os #file system methode
import hashlib #hashing function
import sys #system methods
import time #time conversions

# Python 3rd Party Libraries
from prettytable import PrettyTable     # pip install prettytable

# Local Functions
def GetFileMetaData(fileName):
    #obtain file system metadata
    try:
    
        metaData         = os.stat(fileName)       # Use the stat method to obtain meta data
        fileSize         = metaData.st_size         # Extract fileSize and MAC Times
        timeLastAccess   = metaData.st_atime
        timeLastModified = metaData.st_mtime
        timeCreated      = metaData.st_ctime      
    
        macTimeList = [timeLastModified, timeCreated, timeLastAccess]   # Group the MAC Times in a List
        return True, None, fileSize, macTimeList

    except Exception as err:
        return False, str(err), None, None

# Psuedo Constants

# Start of the Script
tbl = PrettyTable(['FilePath','FileSize','UTC-Modified', 'UTC-Accessed', 'UTC-Created', 'SHA-256 HASH'])
#file check
while True:
    targetFolder = input("Enter Target Folder: ")
    if os.path.isdir(targetFolder):
        break
    else:
        print("\nInvalid Folder ... Please Try Again") 


print("Walking: ", targetFolder, "\n")
print()


for currentRoot, dirList, fileList in os.walk(targetFolder):

    for nextFile in fileList:
    
        fullPath = os.path.join(currentRoot, nextFile)
        absPath  = os.path.abspath(fullPath)
        fileSize = os.path.getsize(absPath)
        success, errInfo, fileSize, macList = GetFileMetaData(absPath)     
    
        if success:
            #convert to readable Greenich Time
            modTime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(macList[0]))
            accTime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(macList[1]))               
            creTime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(macList[2]))  
    #hashing function        
    with open(absPath, 'rb') as target:
        fileContents = target.read()
        sha256Obj = hashlib.sha256()
        sha256Obj.update(fileContents)
        hexDigest = sha256Obj.hexdigest()                
            
                    
    tbl.add_row( [ absPath, fileSize,modTime, accTime, creTime, hexDigest] )                    
        
 
   
tbl.align = "l" # align the columns left justified
# display the table
print (tbl.get_string(sortby="FileSize", reversesort=True))
     
print("\nScript-End\n")
```

Comment: The code that gets the hash needs to be inside the `for nextFile in fileList:` loop. Add a level of indentation.

Comment: Since it's not in the loop, it only hashes the last file in `fileList`.